# Create new columns with mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's assume that I have data like below:

```
structure(list(A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8), B = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 9.2, 9, 0, 0, 1), C = c(2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I would like to create dummy variables for these columns for which proportion of 0's is greater than `0.5`. These dummy variables would have value `0` if there is `0` in original column, and `1` if opposite. How can I accomplish that with `dplyr`? I was thinking of `data %>% mutate_if(~mean(. == 0) > .5, ~ifelse(. == 0, 0, 1))`, but this operates in place and I need to create new variables named e.g. `A01`, `C01` and preserve the old ones `A` and `C`.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate_if(~mean(. == 0) > .5, funs("01" = ifelse(. == 0, 0, 1)))`

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We wrap with the `funs` and give a different name which will append as suffix

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_if(~mean(. == 0) > .5, funs(`01` = ifelse(. == 0, 0, 1))) %>%
   rename_all(str_remove, "_")
#   A   B C A01 C01
#1  0 0.0 2   0   1
#2  0 1.0 9   0   1
#3  0 1.0 0   0   0
#4  0 0.0 0   0   0
#5  0 0.0 0   0   0
#6  0 1.0 9   0   1
#7  0 4.0 0   0   0
#8  0 9.2 0   0   0
#9  0 9.0 0   0   0
#10 0 0.0 0   0   0
#11 1 0.0 0   1   0
#12 8 1.0 8   1   1
```

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we can use `mutate` with `across`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(where(~ mean(. == 0) > .5), 
          ~ as.integer(. != 0), .names = '{.col}01'))
```

Comment: funs() was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0. Now you need to use named functions. 

`df1 %>% mutate_if(~mean(. == 0) > .5, list(suffix = function(.) {ifelse(. == 0, 0, 1)} ))`

Comment: @user1582665 thanks, I added the `across` that is mostly current